# Directory '~' ended up in one of my folders

Tags: files, filenames, rm

A directory named `~` appeared in a folder under `~/Projects/myproject/~`.

Doing

```
ls -al ~/Projects/myproject
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser  staff      102 20 Sep 11:32 ~
```

I don't want to try removing it with rm because I have a feeling it will remove my whole home dir.

Is there any safe way to get rid of it, or any ideas on how it got there in the first place?

Comment: try rm -i ? and confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly indicate the `~` file on current directory by preceding it with `./`:

```
cd ~/Projects/myproject
rm ./~
```

Or just use the full path:

```
rm ~/Projects/myproject/~
```